# What is SSH_CONNECTIO in phpinfo

Tags: ssh, php

I see this line in the phpinfo:

```
Environment
SSH_CONNECTION  84.143.217.132 51075 111.243.0.218 31130
```

Is this SSH tunnel? What is this?

Comment: It's not so clear what you are asking for me?

Answer (score 1):

Upon a successful connection, OpenSSH sets several environment variables.

> `SSH_CONNECTION` shows the address of the client, the outgoing port on the client, the address of the server and the incoming port on the server.

So it identifies the client and server ends of the connection. You can read more about that here: [Wikibooks.org/OpenSSH/Client applications](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Applications).